# Transaction commit error is not captured in EJB code

Tags: database, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions, wildfly

When I shutdown DB after flush() and before commit(), an exception is logged but not captured by the code:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class OuterService {

    @EJB InnerService innerService;

    public String outerMethod() {
        try {
            innerService.innerMethod();
            return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "failure";
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class InnerService {

    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

    public void innerMethod() {
        em.persist(new Entity());
        em.flush();
    } //put the breakpoint here
}
```

I run the code in debug mode and set a breakpoint after flush but before exiting the transactional method. When the execution is paused, I stop the db service and then resume the code.

An exception is logged with the following root cause:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution
>   unknown.

but it is not captured by the outer try..catch block and the method successfully completes. It seems that JTA implementation suffocates the exception. How can I be notified of an error?

I already tried BMT and CDI events but none worked. Plain JDBC and JPA (Hibernate, with built-in and C3p0 pools) in Java SE environment, however, do work.

My setup: Ubuntu 17.10, Wildfly 10, MySQL 5.7.20, Connector/J 5.1.44

Here is the log (some lines removed because of character limit):

```
2018-01-07 12:38:44,980 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hibernate: insert into Entity values ( )
2018-01-07 12:39:06,027 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (default task-1) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@f0b0aed[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@327b7fd0 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1515316110106 lastValidated=1515316098805 lastCheckedOut=1515316124981 trackByTx=true pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@a4e7bad mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@42037075[pool=TestDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@306327f6[connectionListener=f0b0aed connectionManager=6110d60 warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 jndiName=java:/datasources/TestDS] txSync=TransactionSynchronization@360457732{tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000101:-7fd727eb:5a51e37d:1d status: ActionStatus.COMMITTING > wasTrackByTx=true enlisted=true cancel=false}]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1552)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection.commit(LocalManagedConnection.java:96)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.LocalXAResourceImpl.commit(LocalXAResourceImpl.java:172)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:96)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at InnerService$$$view26.innerMethod(Unknown Source)
    at OuterService.outerMethod(OuterService.java:23)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at OuterService$$$view33.outerMethod(Unknown Source)
    at RestManager.test(RestManager.java:112)

2018-01-07 12:39:06,032 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) ARJUNA016039: onePhaseCommit on < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=47, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff7f000101:-7fd727eb:5a51e37d:1d, node_name=mypc, branch_uid=0:ffff7f000101:-7fd727eb:5a51e37d:20, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/datasources/TestDS > (LocalXAResourceImpl@306327f6[connectionListener=f0b0aed connectionManager=6110d60 warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 jndiName=java:/datasources/TestDS]) failed with exception XAException.XAER_RMFAIL: org.jboss.jca.core.spi.transaction.local.LocalXAException: IJ001156: Could not commit local transaction
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.LocalXAResourceImpl.commit(LocalXAResourceImpl.java:177)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAOnePhaseResource.commit(XAOnePhaseResource.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:91)
    at InnerService$$$view26.innerMethod(Unknown Source)
    at OuterService.outerMethod(OuterService.java:23)
    at OuterService$$$view33.outerMethod(Unknown Source)
    at RestManager.test(RestManager.java:112)
    at RestManager$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.test(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.core.spi.transaction.local.LocalResourceException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection.commit(LocalManagedConnection.java:103)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.LocalXAResourceImpl.commit(LocalXAResourceImpl.java:172)
    ... 248 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1552)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection.commit(LocalManagedConnection.java:96)
    ... 249 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated on this and it sounds to me as an issue. I created the jira here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBTM-2983. Feel free to follow discussion there if it's confirmed so.

I expect the caller should be informed that there was an exception during commit. Btw. in case I of some further investigation I created a small test project based of your issue: https://github.com/ochaloup/catch-ejb-exception-test.git

Comment: The issue is marked as Resolved in JIRA, so I guess I should accept this answer. BTW, is there a temporary workaround for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: the issue is marked as resolved and should be part of the next Narayana release (5.7.3.Final). Now it depends on when the component upgrade will be included in the WildFly release. On the temporary workaround: that's tricky, I'm not sure if there is some :/ Will try to think about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. There could be several causes.

First I would try is to increase the `net_write_timeout` property in your mysql configuration.

Also your Exception is caused by error code `XAException.XAER_RMFAIL`

[Jboss Javadoc: XAException](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/javax/transaction/xa/XAException.html):

> Error code indicating that the resource manager has failed and is not
>   available.

So it seems that `PersistenceContext` is broken or invalid because of break point interruption.